# Microsoft Excel - Multiple Results Returned Vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Goal: I want to understand for each customer ID, every transaction that the customer ID has actioned.

Datasets (I copy a screenshot below)

- 1: A list of rewards
- 2: A list of transactions

Request:

1. I want to find every transaction datestamp in the transactions tab that is associated with the customer ID in the rewards tab (column C in the rewards tab links to column C in the transactions tab)
2. I want the search to return every transaction datestamp (column E in the transactions tab) that the customer has made.
3. I want this presented vertically in the spreadsheet, starting in F1 on the rewards tab and moving across the spreadsheet for customer A1.
4. I want the datestamp to be presented as a date stamp and not a string of numbers.
5. I want to be able to drag this formula down on the rewards tab for every other customer in column A.

***Rewards Tab:***
[image]

***Transactions Tab:***
[image]

[FYI Harun24HR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dktSa.png)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have excel-365?

Answer (score 0):

With `EXCEL-365` you can use `FILTER()` function like

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Transactions!$E$2:$E$500,Transactions!$A$2:$A$500=A2))
```

For older version of excel you can try-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Transactions!$E$2:$E$500,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($2:$500)-ROW($A$1))/(Transactions!$A$2:$A$500=$A2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Comment: Hi Harun24HR, thanks for answering. When trying your solution I am returned with a #CALC error. Do you know why this is? I have added the screenshot to the main body of the question.

Comment: Can you please share a sample workbook via google drive or dropbox? You are using MAC excel. What is excel version?